# Mathematica implementation of Benjamini-Hochberg Multiple Testing

Tags: probability-or-statistics, code-request

I was wondering whether anyone was aware of Mathematica code for the Benjamini-Hochberg algorithm for multiple testing?

Answer (score 1):

A long delay I know, but I wanted the answer to this too, so thought I'd post what I've managed to come up with just in case anybody else stumbles across this in future!

```
benjaminiHochberg[pList_,fdr_] := (Module[{sortedList, order, lenno, bhQ, pAndQ, pQTest, 
    cutoff},
   sortedList = Sort@pList;
   order = Ordering@pList;
   lenno = Length@pList;
   bhQ = fdr (#/lenno) & /@ Range@lenno;
   pAndQ = Transpose@{sortedList, bhQ};
   pQTest = #[[1]] >= #[[2]] & /@ pAndQ;
   cutoff = -1 + FirstPosition[Reverse@pQTest, False][[1]];
   order[[;; lenno - cutoff]]])
```

If you feed this function a list of p-values in the first argument (`pList_`)
and your required false discovery rate in the second (`fdr_`), it will return the positions in your original list of p-values of those that are deemed significant (I think!).